# App with TSocketConnection : Error on register server application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-2007, datasnap

I have an 3-tier app developed using TSocketConnection. It has the client app and the server app, both developed in Delphi XE.

I know when i install the app in a new machine, i have to register the server in command prompt running as Administrator, like this :

```
myserver.exe -regserver
```

I always did it and always worked. But somehow, there is a new Windows 10 machine that won't accept this command. I run the command, no message is shown. When i try to run my app, i get this error message :

```
object not available: {00421208-b759-11d5-a92f-0010dcb08b6c}
```

It seems something is blocking the access to the registry in this machine.The current user is logged as administrator and i removed all anti-virus and disabled Windows Defender.

Is there another way to register the app server, so i could at least debug what is going on ?

Thanks

Comment: I myself have been having very strange issues lately regarding the Windows registry, and of course nobody believes me... https://superuser.com/questions/1315716/windows-acting-like-theres-two-registries